# Request processing failed; Mail server connection failed, Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 25; timeout -1;

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

**[How to resolve the error when I am trying to send email using authcontroller.java class?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9Zes.png)**

When I am using email service alone in different project it is working properly but when I integrated it with my main project it is not working.

**org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection  failed; nested exception is com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException:  Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 25; timeout -1;    nested exception is:java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out:**

AuthController.java Class

```
@CrossOrigin("*")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/auth")
public class AuthController {

@Autowired
private UserRepo userRepo;
@Autowired
private RoleRepo roleRepo;
@Autowired
private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
@Autowired
private JwtUtils jwtUtils;
@Autowired
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
@Autowired 
private EmailService emailService;

// POST request for adding user
@PostMapping("/register")
public ResponseEntity<?> registerUser(@Valid @RequestBody SignupRequest signupRequest) {
if (userRepo.existsByEmail(signupRequest.getEmail())) {
return ResponseEntity
.badRequest()
.body(new MessageResponse("Error: Email is already in use!"));
}

User user = new User(signupRequest.getEmail(),
signupRequest.getName(),
passwordEncoder.encode(signupRequest.getPassword()),
signupRequest.getAddress());
//signupRequest.setRole(new ArraySet<>(Set.of("ROLE_USER","")));
signupRequest.setRole("ROLE_ADMIN");
String strRoles = signupRequest.getRole();
Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
if (strRoles==null) {
Role userRole = roleRepo.findByRoleName("ROLE_ADMIN")
.orElseThrow(()-> new RuntimeException("Error: role not found"));
roles.add(userRole);
}
user.setRoles(roles);
userRepo.save(user);
String emailId = user.getEmail();
emailService.sendTextEmail(emailId);
return ResponseEntity
.status(201)
.body(new MessageResponse("User created successfully"));
}


// POST request for validating user
@PostMapping("/authenticate")
public ResponseEntity<?> authenticateUser(@Valid @RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest) {
Authentication authentication = authenticationManager
.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginRequest.getEmail(),
loginRequest.getPassword()));

SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
String jwt = jwtUtils.generateToken(authentication);
UserDetailsImpl userDetailsImpl = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();
List<String> roles = userDetailsImpl.getAuthorities()
.stream()
.map(i->i.getAuthority())
.collect(Collectors.toList());

return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtResponse(jwt,
userDetailsImpl.getId(),
userDetailsImpl.getEmail(),
roles));
}

@GetMapping("/")
public ResponseEntity<?> getUser() {
UserDetailsImpl userDetailsImpl = (UserDetailsImpl) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()
.getPrincipal();
Long id = userDetailsImpl.getId();
Optional<User> optional = userRepo.findById(id);
return ResponseEntity.ok(optional.get());
}
}
```

User.java Class

```
@Setter
@Getter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
//@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "`user`", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "email")})
public class User {

    public User(String email, String name, String password, String address) {
        this.email = email;
        this.name = name;
        this.password = password;
        this.address = address;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "userId")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    
    @Size(max = 50)
    @Email
    private String email;
    @Size(max = 50)
    @NotBlank
    private String name;
    @Size(max = 100)
    @NotBlank
    private String password;
    @Size(max = 50)
    @NotBlank
    private String address;
    
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "cart", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "userId"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name  = "foodId"))
    private List<Food> cart = new ArrayList<Food>();
    
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "userId"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name  = "roleId"))
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Role>();
    
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "orders", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "userId"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "orderId"))
    private List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<Order>();

}
```

EmailServiceImpl.java Class

```
    @Service
    public class EmailServiceImpl implements EmailService {
    
        private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory
                .getLogger(EmailServiceImpl.class);
        @Autowired
        private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;
    
        @Override
        //Sending User Object
        public void sendTextEmail(String mail) {
            logger.info("Simple Email sending start");
    
            SimpleMailMessage simpleMessage = new SimpleMailMessage();
            simpleMessage.setTo(mail); //Enter customer email 
            simpleMessage.setSubject("User Registration");
            simpleMessage.setText("Dear customer welcome to hungerbuddy.");
            javaMailSender.send(simpleMessage);
            logger.info("Simple Email sent");
    
        }
    }
```

I have added the image of properties file after removing my emailId and password.

**ThankYou**

Comment: I think, your code is not using port 587 for email service. Use this property: spring.mail.port=587

Comment: There was typing error in my properties file in port 587 calling line. Thankyou for helping.